# How can I receive remote stream using [agora.io]

Tags: webrtc, agora.io

I can't receive any data from the remote stream and the div with the id of the remote streams that I've created with Javascript doesn't show I don't understand why ! The Javascript code doesn't work on the browser it's a little bit strange it's my first time coming across with this kind of problem please help me solve it.

This is the code :

```
// Local stream

// rtc object
var rtc = {
  client: null,
  joined: false,
  published: false,
  localStream: null,
  remoteStreams: [],
  params: {}
};

// Options for joining a channel
var option = {
  mode: "rtc",
  codec: "h264",
  appID: "22a27d03d0edf54749a03597d72ad82aaa78",
  channel: "qiossa",
  uid: null,
  token: "006a27d03d0edf54749a03597d72ad82aaaIADHJF46Q3g4Jn+mjfRgh5Le76OO2BpUfEuvw1Qv+35XKFwgy+4AAAAAEACfOV6k44bGXgEAAQCIh8Ze"
};


// Create a client
rtc.client = AgoraRTC.createClient({mode: option.mode, codec: option.codec});

// Initialize the client
rtc.client.init(option.appID, function () {
  console.log("init success");
  }, (err) => {
  console.error(err);
});


// Join a channel
rtc.client.join(option.token, option.channel, option.uid, function (uid) {
  console.log("join channel: " + option.channel + " success, uid: " + uid);
  rtc.params.uid = uid;
}, function(err) {
  console.error("client join failed", err);
});

// Create a local stream
rtc.localStream = AgoraRTC.createStream({
  streamID: rtc.params.uid,
  audio: true,
  video: true,
  screen: false,
});


// Initialize the local stream
rtc.localStream.init(function () {
  console.log("init local stream success");
  // play stream with html element id "local_stream"
  rtc.localStream.play("local_stream");
}, function (err) {
  console.error("init local stream failed ", err);
});


// Publish the local stream
rtc.client.publish(rtc.localStream, function (err) {
  console.log("publish failed");
  console.error(err);
});

//*************************************************************************************************************//

// Remote stream

rtc.client.on("stream-added", function (evt) {  
  var remoteStream = evt.stream;
  var id = remoteStream.getId();
  if (id !== rtc.params.uid) {
    rtc.client.subscribe(remoteStream, function (err) {
      console.log("stream subscribe failed", err);
    });
  }
  console.log("stream-added remote-uid: ", id);
});


rtc.client.on("stream-subscribed", function (evt) {
  var remoteStream = evt.stream;
  var id = remoteStream.getId();
  // Add a view for the remote stream.

  let streamDiv=document.createElement("div"); // Create a new div for every stream
  streamDiv.id= id;                            // Assigning id to div
  streamDiv.style.transform="rotateY(180deg)"; // Takes care of lateral inversion (mirror image)
  remoteContainer.appendChild(streamDiv);

  // Play the remote stream.
  remoteStream.play("remote_video_" + id);
  console.log("stream-subscribed remote-uid: ", id);
});
```

[Photo of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8JOB.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[console problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q56pw.png)

```
// Local stream

// rtc object
var rtc = {
  client: null,
  joined: false,
  published: false,
  localStream: null,
  remoteStreams: [],
  params: {}
};

// Options for joining a channel
var option = {
  mode: "rtc",
  codec: "h264",
  appID: "",
  channel: "qiossa",
  uid: null,
  token: "006a27d03d0edf54749a03597d72ad82aaaIADkVIvop7lo0OEkm/7Tuz/Tp4M+TXhFd9DkLAAwu9fNllwgy+4AAAAAEAD4aAmV2FzKXgEAAQBjT8pe"
};


// Create a client
rtc.client = AgoraRTC.createClient({mode: option.mode, codec: option.codec});

// Initialize the client
rtc.client.init(option.appID, function () {
  console.log("init success");
  }, (err) => {
  console.error(err);
});


// Join a channel
rtc.client.join(option.token, option.channel, option.uid, function (uid) {
  console.log("join channel: " + option.channel + " success, uid: " + uid);
  rtc.params.uid = uid;

  // Create a local stream
rtc.localStream = AgoraRTC.createStream({
  streamID: rtc.params.uid,
  audio: true,
  video: true,
  screen: false,
});


// Initialize the local stream
rtc.localStream.init(function () {
  console.log("init local stream success");
  // play stream with html element id "local_stream"
  rtc.localStream.play("local_stream");
}, function (err) {
  console.error("init local stream failed ", err);
});


// Publish the local stream
rtc.client.publish(rtc.localStream, function (err) {
  console.log("publish failed");
  console.error(err);
});


}, function(err) {
  console.error("client join failed", err);
});


//*************************************************************************************************************//

// Remote stream

rtc.client.on("stream-added", function (evt) {  
  var remoteStream = evt.stream;
  var id = remoteStream.getId();
  if (id !== rtc.params.uid) {
    rtc.client.subscribe(remoteStream, function (err) {
      console.log("stream subscribe failed", err);
    });
  }
  console.log("stream-added remote-uid: ", id);
});


rtc.client.on("stream-subscribed", function (evt) {
  var remoteStream = evt.stream;
  var id = remoteStream.getId();
  // Add a view for the remote stream.

  addView(id);

  // Play the remote stream.
  remoteStream.play("remote_video_" + id);
  console.log("stream-subscribed remote-uid: ", id);
});


rtc.client.on("stream-removed", function (evt) {
  var remoteStream = evt.stream;
  var id = remoteStream.getId();
  // Stop playing the remote stream.
  remoteStream.stop("remote_video_" + id);
  // Remove the view of the remote stream. 
  removeView(id);
  console.log("stream-removed remote-uid: ", id);
});

// Leave the channel
rtc.client.leave(function () {
  // Stop playing the local stream
  rtc.localStream.stop();
  // Close the local stream
  rtc.localStream.close();
  // Stop playing the remote streams and remove the views
  while (rtc.remoteStreams.length > 0) {
    var stream = rtc.remoteStreams.shift();
    var id = stream.getId();
    stream.stop();
    removeView(id);
  }
  console.log("client leaves channel success");
}, function (err) {
  console.log("channel leave failed");
  console.error(err);
});




function addView (id, show) {
  if (!$("#" + id)[0]) {
    $("<div/>", {
      id: "remote_video_panel_" + id,
      class: "video-view",
    }).appendTo("#video")

    $("<div/>", {
      id: "remote_video_" + id,
      class: "video-placeholder",
    }).appendTo("#remote_video_panel_" + id)

    $("<div/>", {
      id: "remote_video_info_" + id,
      class: "video-profile " + (show ? "" :  "hide"),
    }).appendTo("#remote_video_panel_" + id)

    $("<div/>", {
      id: "video_autoplay_"+ id,
      class: "autoplay-fallback hide",
    }).appendTo("#remote_video_panel_" + id)
  }
}
function removeView (id) {
  if ($("#remote_video_panel_" + id)[0]) {
    $("#remote_video_panel_"+id).remove()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The local stream needs to be created, initialised, played and published within the join function. 
This is the corrected code for the rtc.client.join() function:

```
rtc.client.join(option.token, option.channel, option.uid, (uid)=>{
console.log("join channel: " + option.channel + " success, uid: " + uid);
rtc.params.uid = uid;
// Create a local stream
rtc.localStream = AgoraRTC.createStream({
  streamID: rtc.params.uid,
  audio: true,
  video: true,
  screen: false,
});


// Initialize the local stream
rtc.localStream.init(function () {
  console.log("init local stream success");
  // play stream with html element id "local_stream"
  rtc.localStream.play("local_stream");
}, function (err) {
  console.error("init local stream failed ", err);
});


// Publish the local stream
rtc.client.publish(rtc.localStream, function (err) {
  console.log("publish failed");
  console.error(err);
});
}, function(err) {
  console.error("client join failed", err);
});
```

Get back to us for any further queries.

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work. I will try to send a screenshot with the code in an answer